Poisson process and a stopping time
Let $(N_t)$ be a Poisson process. For $a \in \mathbb{N}$, is the random variable
$$\tau = \inf \lbrace t \ge 0 : N_t = a \rbrace$$
a stopping time with respect to $\left(\mathcal{F}_t^N\right)$?
I thought that it is enough to write $\lbrace \tau \le t\rbrace = \lbrace N_t \ge a\rbrace \in \mathcal{F}_t^N$. But if $N_t \ge a$, it doesn't necessary mean that $\tau \le t$, because it can have a jump of height $2$ and just jump over the level $a$ (with probability $0$, but still, it may happen), right?
So, do we need to assume something more? Like that the filtration satisfies the usual conditions?

What has probability zero may not happen.

What is your definition of "Poisson process"?

A right-continuous (a.s.) process, starting at $0$ with stationary and independent increments.

And increasing paths, increasing  only by jumps of unit size? (To distinguish it from other Lévy processes, such as Brownian motion.)

Sorry, I should have specified. By stationary increments, I mean that $N_t - N_s \sim \hbox{Poiss}((t-s)\lambda)$. So increasing paths and jumps of unit size (almost surely) is a consequence

And so a jump of height 2 has probability 0.

Maybe I don't understand something, but there are trajectories, which have jump of height $2$ (but the probability they occur is $0$). I can forget about them when calculating probabilities, but here I'm operating on sets. So why don't I have to write like $\lbrace \tau \le t \rbrace = \lbrace N_t \ge a \rbrace \setminus \lbrace \hbox{ N had jump of height 2 and it jumped over level a }\rbrace$ ? If I knew the filtration contains all sets of probability $0$, then it would be fine, but what if it doesn't?

Yes, things are more delicate when the filtration isn't complete, but you are describing the process using a.s. properties (like "right-continuous (a.s.)"). It's not even clear that $\tau$ is a random variable, let alone a stopping time, without more precise knowledge of the sample space and the filtration.
